# Improving performance of loading data to GPU

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, cupy

#### Approach 1 (scipy sparse matrix -> numpy array -> cupy array; approx 20 minutes per epoch)

I have written neural network from scratch (no pytorch or tensorflow) and since numpy does not run directly on gpu, I have written it in cupy (Simply changing `import numpy as np` to `import cupy as cp` and then using `cp` instead of `np` works.) It reduced the training time from tens hours for numpy to 25 minutes (for cupy) for single epoch. However I wanted to reduce it further. Increasing mini batch size did not help. So, I thought the issue might not be with forward and backward pass which involved actual matrix multiplications but must be with data loading and moving it to GPU. So I removed all forward and backward pass call with only data loading part left behind. And it was still taking approx 20 minutes. So, it seems most of the time was consumed by data loading. Here is the code:

```
class Model():  
      
    def train(self, X, Y, epochs, mbSize):

        for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs), desc='epoch'):
              
            for mbStartIdx in tqdm(range(0, X.shape[0]-mbSize+1, mbSize),desc='mb'):

                mbX = cp.asarray(X[mbStartIdx: mbStartIdx + mbSize].toarray()) # line 1
                mbY = cp.asarray(Y[mbStartIdx: mbStartIdx + mbSize].toarray()) # line 2 

model = Model()
# loading dataset X and Y values from disk
X = load_npz('X.npz') # line 3
Y = load_npz('Y.npz') # line 4
model.train(X, Y, epochs=200, mbSize=64) # takes approx 20 minutes for 1 epoch
```

I have created one hot vectors `X` and `Y` as [scipy CSR sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) and saved them to the file (as saving numpy arrays was taking several GBs). I am loading them from the file on line 3 and 4.

On line 1 and 2,

- we first index sparse vectors to create minibatch `X[mbStartIdx: mbStartIdx + mbSize]`. (Loading all samples from X and Y in GPU requires more than 15 GB of RAM always crashing colab notebook. Hence I am loading single minibatch into GPU at a time.)
- then we convert them to numpy array `.toarray()`
- then we finally move numpy array to CUDA `cp.asarray(..)`

Check [model 1 / point 8 in this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10oauLpHKT37hl2pdzZO5K8wqNKzo-q7Y?authuser=2#scrollTo=-QeGTyp2RXfS)

#### Approach 2 (cupy sparse matrix -> cupy array; approx 10 minutes per epoch)

Cupy also [supports csr sparse matrix](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupyx.scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
class Model2():  
      
    def train(self, X, Y, epochs, mbSize):

        for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs), desc='epoch'):
              
            for mbStartIdx in tqdm(range(0, X.shape[0]-mbSize+1, mbSize),desc='mb'):

                mbX = X[mbStartIdx: mbStartIdx + mbSize].toarray() # line 3
                mbY = Y[mbStartIdx: mbStartIdx + mbSize].toarray() # line 4

model2 = Model2()
# X = load_npz('X.npz')
# Y = load_npz('Y.npz')
cupy_csr_x = csr_matrix(X) # line 3
cupy_csr_y = csr_matrix(Y) # line 4
model2.train(cupy_csr_x, cupy_csr_y, epochs=200, mbSize=64) # takes approx 10 minutes for 1 epoch
```

Here,

- I first converted all of `X` and `Y` to cupy sparse matrix (line 3 and 4) and
- then converted them to cupy array (line 1 and 2)

Check [model 2 / point 9 in this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10oauLpHKT37hl2pdzZO5K8wqNKzo-q7Y?authuser=2#scrollTo=1YlIU3gGfZWj).

How can I improve the performance further?

**Update**

Created Model3 same as Model2 with difference that we are casting CuPy array to `ushort`, which is OK since X and Y are one hot vectors and does not require any precision. Also increased mini batch size from 64 to 2048. Now one epoch takes approx 6 minutes.

**PS:** get dataset files from here: [X.npz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qw4yWpRGMOv83S7d63s10bXrTCt_wD4G/view?usp=share_link), [Y.npz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_V7NbGXm1hVlLpndOKeAj7A5lHM94y_/view?usp=share_link)